# Delete Button for Every Input Added

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, button

I'm building this beginner react-native application that lists down its ongoing tasks and also allows users to delete the tasks when needed. I was already able to show each task but I can't figure out how to add a delete button for every task added.

Below is the code that I have come up with but I haven't been able to make a delete button for each task yet.

```
export default function App() {
      const [newTask,setNewTask] = useState();
      const [taskList,setTaskList] = useState([]);

      const convertedTaskList = taskList.map((toDoTask,index)=>({
        id: index+1,
        activity:toDoTask,
        status:'complete'
        }))

      function addTodoHandler(){
      setTaskList([...taskList,newTask])
      }

      return (
      <View style={styleSheet.container}>
        <View style={styleSheet.contentContainer}>
            <View>
                <Text style={styleSheet.sectionTitle}>TO-DO LIST</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styleSheet.taskContainer}>
                {taskList.map((task)=><Text key={task}>{task}</Text>)}
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styleSheet.addTaskWrapper}>
            <TextInput placeholder="Enter Task" onChangeText={(enteredText)=>setNewTask(enteredText)}/>
            <Button title="Add Task" onPress={addTodoHandler}/>
        </View>
      </View>
      );
    }
```

Is there a way for me to make an output just like the picture I attached through the link below?

[Task w/ Delete Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8KAk.png)

Comment: If the answer bellow helped you, consider marking your question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it in the map:

```js
<View style={styleSheet.taskContainer}>
  {taskList.map((task, index)=> (
    <>
      <Text key={task}>{task}</Text>
      <Button title="Delete" onPress={() => setTaskList((prev) => prev.slice(index, 1))} />
    </>
  ))}
</View>
```